# Python3.6 ImportError: cannot import name 'main' Linux RHEL6

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, pip, rhel6

My ultimate goal is to download and install awscli
`http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html`

Seems python and pip are required in order to accomplish my goal.

Installing python via yum isn't working for me, so I downloaded and installed python3 manually as follows:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
```

When I do

> `pip3.6 --version`

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.6", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

**Environment:**
RHEL 6.6
Accessed via ssh

What is going on? How to install pip and python3.6 correctly on my linux box?

*Edit:*

When trying to install via yum it fails so I am trying to avoid using yum:

`[asemani@rcdc9pfda5r Python-3.6.1]$ sudo yum -y install python-pip`

```
[sudo] password for asemeani: 
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package python-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

*Another Edit:*

After importing sys and then called sys.path this is what I get:

```
[asemani@rcdc9pfda5r Python-3.6.1]$ python3.6
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr 28 2017, 11:03:27) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>> quit()
[asemani@rcdc9pfda5r Python-3.6.1]$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
total 32
-rw-------  1 root root  126 Apr 27 23:45 easy_install.py
drwx------ 11 root root 4096 Apr 27 23:45 pip
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Apr 27 23:45 pip-9.0.1.dist-info
drwx------  5 root root 4096 Apr 27 23:45 pkg_resources
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Apr 27 23:45 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  119 Apr 27 23:45 README.txt
drwx------  5 root root 4096 Apr 27 23:45 setuptools
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Apr 27 23:45 setuptools-28.8.0.dist-info
```

Comment: "*Installing python via yum isn't working for me*" - how is it failing?

Comment: Not quit sure but it doesn't seem to find the python or pip package when yumming. I will update my question to include detail

Comment: This looks relevant: https://packaging.python.org/install_requirements_linux/

Comment: Remove it then install again. `yum remove python-pip` then `yum install python-pip`

Comment: @melpomene I was looking at the document earlier today. As mentioned yum doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I believe you manually installed Python 3.6 correctly. You should then have a `python3` and `pip3` commands available from your terminal.
What does `sys.path` contain after `import sys` using `python3`? You should have something like /somepath/python3.6/site-packages in it. Then what does `ls -l /somepath/python3.6/site-packages | grep pip` prints out?

Comment: @QCaron I've edited my question to answer your questions. However I'm still unclear what my problem is?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'main' Faced the same issue once I upgraded it to Python version 10.
Got solution in -- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240
Simply restarting the terminal worked for me.

Comment: Check my answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 72):

You need to edit the pip3 file like so (your path could be different):

```
nano /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
```

And change the import main line so it says:

```
from pip._internal import main
```

After this change, my pip3 started to work and I am on macOS. If you are using Linux, your path could be something like **/usr/bin/pip3**

I found this tip and more information from this thread:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu, but file was in another path:
`sudo nano /usr/bin/pip3`

Answer (score 17):

Don't invoke pip/pip3 directly, which are shortcuts at different locations for different user and they are not well maintained when you upgrade pip (check 'which pip' and 'sudo which pip').

```
 $ sudo python -m pip install xxx  #for python2 
 $ sudo python3 -m pip install xxx  #for python3
```

These commands do not take shortcuts and directly invoke pip module, which is maintained very well (also works on Windows)

Answer (score 17):

My OS is Linux Mint 18

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/pip3
```

Change

```
from pip import main
```

To

```
from pip._internal import main
```

Comment: This is basically copy of the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

`sudo chmod -R a+rx /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

You can see the problem right there in your `ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` output that your pip directory is only readable by the owner, which is root.

Answer (score 5):

Do a `cd /usr/bin`

Then `sudo nano pip` so as to edit the pip file

Change `from pip import main` to `from pip._internal import main`

This will resolve the issue

Comment: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

try the following as a way around the issue until it got solved

```
sudo python -m pip --version
>> pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
sudo python -m pip install numpy --upgrade
>> Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.14.2)
```

Comment: Worked for me on High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know the answer, but: that error indicates that the script can find *some* package called `pip`, but not the right one. Probably, an old version of pip, from back before they created a `main` method (you can check `pip.__version__` from the python shell).

I'm willing to bet that you still have another, older version of python installed which has its own version of pip. For some reason your pythonpath is loading that one instead of the one that goes with py3.6.

Some possibilities to look into:

- I don't know anything about redhat, but is there some redhat-specific way of choosing the "default python" to be used?
- Is the shebang line at the top of the pip script something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/python3.6` like it should be?
- Is it possible to modify your shell's PATH so that the downloaded python is used?
- Is it possible to change your PYTHONPATH (i think it gets added to the default value of `sys.path` inside python; look it up) so that it loads the new pip instead of the old pip?

Comment: Python 2.x is still the default Python version for many Linux / Unix based operating systems. Be careful with "choosing the default python to be used".

Answer (score 1):

My OS was Mac sierra and I had to change the following line

`from pip import main`

into

`from pip._internal import main`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the get pip script was missing the fact that more than 1 version of python could reside on a machine. So I added the following lines:

```
PY2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
```

For some reason it was missing this. Anyway this worked for me. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps to solve the problem --(Ubuntu-Debian)

step 1 - Go to directory

> cd usr/bin/

and open pip3 file using gedit or nano(via terminal) .

Step 2- change `from pip import main`  into  `from pip._internal import main`

P.S - If you donot have permission to change use command - `sudo chmod 777 pip3` and save this file.

Hope this helps!!