# Why is my pip braking after updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My pip broke after I ran

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

When I run this command

`pip -V`

or any other commands I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Why is it breaking? I have python3 installed. I have a solution but I need to understand why it broke after upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: can you try using pip3 instead of pip.. i see a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675074/python3-6-importerror-cannot-import-name-main-linux-rhel6)

Comment: i will try that, thank but i have not got the explanation why it brakes right yet.

Comment: It also happened on my virtual machine, when I was just experimenting with different Linux distros, I didn't want to search for the root cause of this problem, but I am fav'ing to follow answers.

Comment: i solved it with this `python -m pip uninstall pip` but still suggested i update pip

Comment: The Python3 formula does not override pip in HOMEBREW_PREFIX/bin. The part that overrides pip is when a user manually runs a pip3 install --upgrade pip and that logic is handled by pip itself rather than Homebrew or the Python3 formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` authors were warning for many years to not [`import pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). Finally at version 10 they restructured their code.

Your `/usr/bin/pip` was not upgraded (probably because `pip install -U pip` installed new `/usr/local/bin/pip`) so it uses the old API before renaming.

If that's the case I recommend to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`.